# Filtering this collection and writing to txt file

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell script: -

```
$Files = gci "e:\sourcecontrolledprojects\genericsolution\genericsolution" -recurse | Where {$_.extension -eq ".dll"} 
$Files | Format-Table FullName |
```

How can I filter this to only return Dlls containing test in the filename, and write each Dll path on a new line in a text file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is a combination of @manojlds and @jon's. Use the filter parameter, expand the path and write it to a text file in a streaming way (instead of assigning the output to a variable first). For readability, code is on two lines :

```
$path = 'e:\sourcecontrolledprojects\genericsolution\genericsolution'
gci $path -filter *test*.dll -recurse | select -expand fullname | out-file .\dlls.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Files = gci "e:\sourcecontrolledprojects\genericsolution\genericsolution" -recurse -filter "*test*.dll"  
$Files | foreach-object {$_.fullname} | out-file testdll.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gci e:\sourcecontrolledprojects\genericsolution\genericsolution -Include "*test*.dll" -Recurse | 
select -expand fullname | out-file test.txt
```

Caution on the `Format-Table` you were trying to use. Once you do that, what you are piping after that will be formatting objects and not the original objects you wanted. Use it only as  a last step when you want to format your output on the host.